# Replace the data in a column in a file with the data in a row from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I'm new working with linux enviroment and i need to write a script to process some data.

I have a file that looks like this:

File A:

```
1    X   1    1.0
2    X   1    1.0
3    X   1    1.0
4    Y   2    1.0
5    Y   2    1.0
6    Z   3    1.0
```

and another file that looks like this:

File B:

```
1 0.5
2 0.3
3 0.2
```

I need to replace the numbers from the 4th column of File A, with the numbers that appear in the 2nd column of file B, but it has to be matching the numbers from the 3rd column of file A with the numbers of the 1st column of file B

The desired oputput is:

```
1    X   1    0.5
2    X   1    0.5
3    X   1    0.5
4    Y   2    0.3
5    Y   2    0.3
6    Z   3    0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't sort the files, use Awk, which is (like `join`) designed for handling delimited data.

In this case, pass over the second file first, to construct a lookup table, and then use the lookup table to modify each line of the first file as you pass through it.

```
$ cat file2
1 0.5
2 0.3
3 0.2
$ cat file1
1    X   1    1.0
2    X   1    1.0
3    X   1    1.0
4    Y   2    1.0
5    Y   2    1.0
6    Z   3    1.0
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} {$4 = a[$3]} 1' file2 file1
1 X 1 0.5
2 X 1 0.5
3 X 1 0.5
4 Y 2 0.3
5 Y 2 0.3
6 Z 3 0.2
$
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation:  `NR` : number of records (lines, usually) read since the beginning. `FNR` : same, but only for the current File. So `NR==FNR` is only true for the first file read (which, here, serves to "load" the replacement values into the array `a[]`). The `next` at the end of this part ensures that the rest of the treatment is skipped (so only the assignement occurs, while reading the first file). Then (2nd file, the one to be treated) : `NR` is greater than `FNR`, so the first part is skipped, and the rest of the treatment occurs.

Comment: @OlivierDulac, feel free to edit that in to the answer.  :)  Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: I let you do it if you want.. to me editing is to correct typos, not change or add something on the author's words ^^

Answer (score 2):

[Use `join`:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html)

```
join -1 3 -o 1.1,1.2,0,2.2 file1 file2
```

Output with provided files:

```
$ cat file1
1    X   1    1.0
2    X   1    1.0
3    X   1    1.0
4    Y   2    1.0
5    Y   2    1.0
6    Z   3    1.0
$ cat file2
1 0.5
2 0.3
3 0.2
$ join -1 3 -o 1.1,1.2,0,2.2 file1 file2
1 X 1 0.5
2 X 1 0.5
3 X 1 0.5
4 Y 2 0.3
5 Y 2 0.3
6 Z 3 0.2
$
```

Note that both input files must be sorted (for the column you wish to join them on).  That's *lexicographic* sorting required, not numeric, so be sure to `sort -n` the files appropriately if there are more than ten items.  (You can resort again after joining.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can not sort the input then `join` won't work but you can use `sed` instead. The idea is to use `sed` once to transform fileB into a script, then feed that script back to `sed` to transform fileA.

So in one line, using standard POSIX shell command substitution:

```
sed -e "$(sed 's:^\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)$:s/\1  *[^ ]*$/\1    \2/:' file2)" file1
```